# How can I get this query when a column is NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute this query to get a list of all users, groups and emails, but my problem is when the user is not related to any group, so the column radcheck.id_group is = NULL, but I still want to list it.

```sql
SELECT 
    radcheck.username AS username, 
    group.name AS groupname, 
    group.id as gid, 
    useremail.email as email 
FROM useremail, group, radcheck 
WHERE 
    radcheck.username = useremail.username 
    AND group.id = radcheck.id_group;
```

How can I write it correctly?

Comment: This would be one of the many reasons modern explicit JOIN notation was introduced decades ago, and why implicit "comma" join notation has been out of favor for almost as long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit, `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT 
    r.username AS username, 
    g.name AS groupname, 
    g.id as gid, 
    u.email
FROM useremail u
LEFT JOIN radcheck r ON r.username = u.username
LEFT JOIN group g ON g.id = r.id_group
```

It is also often a good practice to use table aliases: they make the query easier to read and maintain (and also allow self-joining tables when needed...).

Comment: @LeandroFabrisMilani: alias fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Use left joins:

```
SELECT 
  radcheck.username AS username, 
  group.name AS groupname, 
  group.id as gid, 
  useremail.email as email 
FROM useremail left join radcheck
ON radcheck.username = useremail.username
left join group
ON group.id = radcheck.id_group
```